# Picklist to Picklist URL Hack Passthrough

Tags: urlhacking

Trying to figure out how to pass the saved result of a picklist in Opportunities to a picklist in Contracts. I can't for the life of me get it to work. I can't even get it to work hardcoded either.

This is what I have so far:

```
https://na13.salesforce.com/800/e?
ctrc7_lkid={!Opportunity.AccountId}&
CF00N30000007Z7hC="Other"&
CF00N30000007Z7t2={!Opportunity.Name}&
retURL=%2F006a0000010VhL3
```

The hardcoded value is Other. I have tried quote marks, no quote marks, %22 in place of quote marks, I have tried the CF id of the field I want to pass through. Just can't figure it out for some reason. Googling isn't shedding much light so trying you guys out.

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't a picklist hack be without "CF..."? If I remember correctly "CF" is needed only for custom lookup fields. What's the actual `<select ... name=".." >` when you inspect the element in your browser? Also - is it a dependent picklist field?

Comment: My bet is on the "dependent picklist" myself; if the controlling value isn't set right, the slave picklist will wipe out the value on page load.

Comment: Thank you all... removing the CF was the key to it all. Knowledge now imprinted on brain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work without any quotes around other.

I have verified in my dev org.

This URL fills the picklist value represented by **00N80000004NQwL** with ***Active***

```
https://na6.salesforce.com/001/e?retURL=%2F001%2Fo&RecordType=0123000000096rr&00N80000004NQwL=Active
```

**See screenshot of pre-filled pick list field**

[image]

**Then if I change the URL to a different pick list value, it works**

```
 https://na6.salesforce.com/001/e?retURL=%2F001%2Fo&RecordType=0123000000096rr&00N80000004NQwL=Target
```

[image]

So this should work, which means the issue is not with your URL, but rather something else.  As @sfdcfox mentions, dependent picklists could be at the bottom of it, and @eyescream points out, you dont need the 'CF' for picklist fields, only lookups, but without knowing more info, its tough to tell.

Bottom line is if you remove the quotes and the 'CF', the URL should work, so if it still is not, you need to look for other factors.